# PatchValue for Upload file in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

So i have edit form page like this
[image]

and form a group like this

```
this.editMateri = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  description: [''],
  thumbnail: [null],
  isPublish: this.status,
  materialCreatorCode: [''],
  tags: this.selectedTags
});
```

and i fetch the data from the server and set the value to the form using `patchValue` like this

```
this.editMateri.patchValue(this.currentMateri);
```

everything works fine, but the problem is with the thumbnail File Upload input, by default it's null so if i update anything except the thumbnail, my thumbnail will goes blank, the thumbnail is set to null. I've been looking for stackblitz code for this but i didn't find any, anyone can help me?

EDIT

in my html like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="label">Thumbnail</label>
    <input type="file" nbInput fullWidth (change)="uploadFile($event)">
</div>
```

and for uploadFile function like this

```
  uploadFile(event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.editMateri.patchValue({
      thumbnail: file
    });
    this.editMateri.get('thumbnail').updateValueAndValidity()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have correctly added the **formControlName** for each of the fields. That's why everything works correctly.

But in the input for uploading the image for thumbnail, you have missed using **formControlName**.

Once you add that in your html, it should work correctly.

Please refer the following html code to be replaced.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="label">Thumbnail</label>
    <input type="file" nbInput fullWidth formControlName="thumbnail" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
</div>
```

Comment: yes turned out it's not about that, in backend they set to file not a string, from patchValue give me a string, so i can't update the form if user not input the file again hmmm, do you know how to avoid that?